# Java 11 : RegEx to Parse Log Message to CSV format

Tags: java, regex, java-11

I need to parse the `logs` and print it in csv format as below, so far I was able to extract the timestamp, message and id from the log message but I was having hard time extracting the fields using the regex, can someone please help me parsing the fields such as `field_1,field_2,field_3,field_4,field_5,field_6,field_9.......` from the input logs.
If the input logs has more fields like `field_10`, `field_11` those needs to be included in the csv headers and values as well, but below is the expected output for the input `logs`

**Expected CSV output**

```
id,timestamp,message,field_1,field_2,field_3,field_4,field_5,field_6,field_9
1,"Wed Jun 19 09:35:40 PDT 2019","test 4",,,,,"test 4",,
2,"Wed Jun 19 09:35:39 PDT 2019","test 3",,,,"test 3",,,
3,"Wed Jun 19 09:35:38 PDT 2019","test 2",,,"test 2",,,,"test 23"
4,"Wed Jun 19 09:35:37 PDT 2019","test 4",,"test 4",,,,,
5,"Wed Jun 19 09:35:37 PDT 2019","test 5",,,"test 10",,,,
6,"Wed Jun 19 09:35:40 PDT 2019","test 6","test 5",,,,,,
10,"Wed Jun 19 09:35:36 PDT 2019","test 10","test 10",,,,,"test 1"
```

**LogParser**

```
public class LogParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String logs = "" +
                "timestamp=\"Wed Jun 19 09:35:36 PDT 2019\" message=\"test 10\" id=10 field_1=\"test 10\" field_6=\"test 1\"\n" +
                "timestamp=\"Wed Jun 19 09:35:37 PDT 2019\" message=\"test 4\" id=4 field_2=\"test 4\"\n" +
                "timestamp=\"Wed Jun 19 09:35:38 PDT 2019\" message=\"test 2\" id=3 field_3=\"test 2\" field_9=\"test 23\"\n" +
                "timestamp=\"Wed Jun 19 09:35:39 PDT 2019\" message=\"test 3\" id=2 field_4=\"test 3\"\n" +
                "timestamp=\"Wed Jun 19 09:35:40 PDT 2019\" message=\"test 4\" id=1 field_5=\"test 4\"\n" +
                "timestamp=\"Wed Jun 19 09:35:37 PDT 2019\" message=\"test 5\" id=5 field_3=\"test 10\"\n" +
                "timestamp=\"Wed Jun 19 09:35:40 PDT 2019\" message=\"test 6\" id=6 field_1=\"test 5\"";
        final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("timestamp=(.+?) message=(.+?) id=(.+?) (.+?)");
        for (String line : logs.split("\n")) {

            Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

            String csvline = null;
            String fields = null;
            if (m.matches()) {
                csvline = (m.group(3)) + "," + m.group(1) + "," + m.group(2);
                fields = m.group(4);
            }
            System.out.println(fields); // having hard time parsing the headers, values and formating

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `(((.+?)="(.+?)")\s*)`
For each line, you will have a match for each field, so you have to iterate through the matches and each match will have four groups:

- the third group will have the field name
- the fourth group will have the field value

Alternatively, you could modify your regex to `timestamp=(.+?) message=(.+?) id=(.+?) (.+?="(.+?)")*`, but I think the above is cleaner and more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Tony BenBrahim's first regex looks like the generic regex I would use. One thing that might make it more intuitive to some developers is to change the first two parenthesis to non-capturing:

`(?:(?:(.+?)="(.+?)")\s*)`

Group one will contain the field name, group two will contain the field value.

If you aren't in control of the format of all the logs you will be parsing, whitespace may be allowed. I would account for whitespace in one more place where I suspect it may be allowed with:

`(?:(?:(.+?)=\s*"(.+?)")\s*)`

An empty value might also be permitted, so I would allow that by changing the second capture group's quantifier:

`(?:(?:(.+?)=\s*"(.*?)")\s*)`

The final modification that might be useful is to trim whitespace off the ends of the two captured fields (i.e. remove leading and trailing whitespace from either end of the captured results):

`(?:(?:\s*(.+?)\s*=\s*"\s*(.*?)\s*")\s*)`

Answer (score 1):

If we are trying to parse an unknown number of key-value pairs from a string then we can use a regex with two capturing groups that matches each key-value pair one at a time, and use it with `find` in a loop.

A key is matched using `\S+` to match one or more non-space characters, and a value is matched using either `"[^"]*"` which is `"` followed by zero or more characters that are not `"`, followed by `"`, or using `\S*` which is zero of more non-space characters.

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\S+)=(\"[^\"]*\"|\\S*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {
  String key = m.group(1);
  String value = m.group(2);
  // Do something with the key and value.
}
```

The following will create your desired output exactly, except your output is missing the required trailing comma after `"test1"`.

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class LogParser {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String logs = "" +
      "timestamp=\"Wed Jun 19 09:35:36 PDT 2019\" message=\"test 10\" id=10 field_1=\"test 10\" field_6=\"test 1\"\n" +
      "timestamp=\"Wed Jun 19 09:35:37 PDT 2019\" message=\"test 4\" id=4 field_2=\"test 4\"\n" +
      "timestamp=\"Wed Jun 19 09:35:38 PDT 2019\" message=\"test 2\" id=3 field_3=\"test 2\" field_9=\"test 23\"\n" +
      "timestamp=\"Wed Jun 19 09:35:39 PDT 2019\" message=\"test 3\" id=2 field_4=\"test 3\"\n" +
      "timestamp=\"Wed Jun 19 09:35:40 PDT 2019\" message=\"test 4\" id=1 field_5=\"test 4\"\n" +
      "timestamp=\"Wed Jun 19 09:35:37 PDT 2019\" message=\"test 5\" id=5 field_3=\"test 10\"\n" +
      "timestamp=\"Wed Jun 19 09:35:40 PDT 2019\" message=\"test 6\" id=6 field_1=\"test 5\"";

    final List<String> knownHeaders = new ArrayList<String>(List.of("id", "timestamp", "message"));
    final List<String> otherHeaders = new ArrayList<String>();
    final List<Map<String, String>> records = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\S+)=(\"[^\"]*\"|\\S+)");
    
    for (String line : logs.split("\n")) {
      Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
      Map<String, String> record = new HashMap<String, String>();
      while (m.find()) {
        String key = m.group(1);
        if (!knownHeaders.contains(key) && !otherHeaders.contains(key)) {
          otherHeaders.add(key);
        } else if (record.containsKey(key)) {
          throw new Exception("Line contains a duplicated field name: " + line);
        }
        record.put(key, m.group(2));
      }
      records.add(record);
    }

    // Sort records in ascending order of id number.
    Collections.sort(records, new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(Map<String, String> left, Map<String, String> right) {
        return Integer.parseInt(left.get("id")) - Integer.parseInt(right.get("id"));
      }
    });
    
    // Sort otherHeaders in lexicographical order.
    Collections.sort(otherHeaders);
    knownHeaders.addAll(otherHeaders);
    String csv = String.join(",", knownHeaders) + "\n";
    
    // Use iterators and hasNext() to prevent unwanted trailing commas and final newline.
    Iterator<Map<String, String>> ri = records.iterator();
    while (ri.hasNext()) {
      Map<String, String> record = ri.next();
      Set<String> keys = record.keySet(); 
      String line = "";
      Iterator<String> hi = knownHeaders.iterator();
      while (hi.hasNext()) {
        String header = hi.next();
        if (keys.contains(header)) line += record.get(header);
        if (hi.hasNext()) line += ",";
      }
      csv += line;
      if (ri.hasNext()) csv += "\n";
    }    

    System.out.println(csv);
  }
}
```

A fuller implementation would require checks in the `compare` function that both `id` fields are not `null` and that they can be converted by `parseInt`.

Also, the regular expression could be extended if necessary to allow escaped `"` or `=` within the quoted value of a key-value pair.